# R: how to compute differences based on a factor's levels?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `mytable` with outcomes for two measurements, A and B, taken to a group of persons.

```
person measure outcome
1      A       3.6
2      A       2.3
3      A       4.2
1      B       3.9
2      B       3.2
3      B       2.7
```

I want to compute for each person the difference between the scores for A and B. That is, I want to obtain:

```
person outcome_diff
1      -0.3
2      -0.9
3       1.5
```

I searched for an answer, but I only found some concerning transformations within the levels of a factor, not across them.

I finally managed to work it out by doing:

```
mytable$outcome[mytable$measure=="B"] <- -1*mytable$outcome[mytable$measure=="B"]
outtable <- aggregate(outcome ~ person, data=mytable, FUN=sum)
```

Although it works, I wonder how to do it without messing up the original table. Furthermore, this solution is quite specific for computing a difference. What could be a more general way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `plyr`:

```
ddply(mytable, "person", summarize,
      outcome_diff = outcome[measure == "A"] -
                     outcome[measure == "B"])
#   person outcome_diff
# 1      1         -0.3
# 2      2         -0.9
# 3      3          1.5
```

Under the assumption that you always have exactly two measures `A` and `B` and in that order, you might also just do `ddply(mytable, "person", summarize, outcome_diff = -diff(outcome))`.

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look at `plyr`. As for the `diff` alternative, I'm not really sure I understand it: since `outcome` has length 6, `diff(outcome)` should have length 5. So in order to obtain the desired `outcome_diff` one should aditionally select the odd elements of `diff(outcome)`, right?

Answer (score 4):

In base you could do this:

```
ans <- sapply(split(myTable, myTable$person), function(x) {
    diff(x[order(x$measure), 3])
})

data.frame(person = names(ans), outcome_dif = ans)

##   person outcome_dif
## 1      1         0.3
## 2      2         0.9
## 3      3        -1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[  , list(outcome_diff = outcome[measure == "A"] - 
              outcome[measure == "B"]),person]
# person outcome_diff
# 1:      1         -0.3
# 2:      2         -0.9
# 3:      3          1.5
```